# How to request Female or Male voice from Microsoft translator

Tags: translation, microsoft-translator

Recently working on Speech using microsoft translate. Just wonder if I can request by female or male voice for speech. This will enable us to learn by voice we prefer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the service supports this ability http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512419.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Matt says, the translator API is fixed to the female voice (Lisa?) and doesn't support other voices like Microsoft Mike.

Similarly Google seem to only provide female voices through their TTS API.

Interestingly, Google are also quite open about their use of http://espeak.sourceforge.net/ to generate speech.

Microsoft are in the process of releasing sample projects for the reverse direction (speech to text) - see 
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/hawaii/students/default.aspx - and this might give you some clues about how to deploy your own service for test to speech - but obviously that would cost you CPU and bandwidth hosting costs.